# Can I put drylok over older drylok

Tags: waterproofing

I've got an old 1953 basement that I want to finish.  The walls are in pretty good shape.  Looks like the previous owner used drylok.  Some areas show some signs of staining, and efflorescence.

Can I use a wire brush to remove the bad spots, and put a cost or two over the existing drylok?  Btw...basement is dry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, drylok can be recoated easily. Depending how bad (or not-bad) the spots are, you might think about whether the super-thick "masonry waterproofer" or the "concrete floor paint" is more appropriate. If staining appears to indicate leaks, probably the thick stuff.

Ease of re-coat is one of several reasons the concrete floor paint is on my shop floor rather than some fancy epoxy product. 5-6X cost differential and not being slippery (without having to add some surface treatment) are two of the others that spring to mind. And, of course, not being gray concrete...

Comment: Wait a minute.....concrete floor paint on the walls?

Comment: If it makes you uncomfortable, then no. And if you've got serious leakage or potential for leakage going on, also no. Otherwise, its a paint for concrete, and the paint police don't descend if you put it on walls. But if you'd rather stick with the thick stuff, that's fine. I've used both, on different (more and less leaky) areas of both floors and walls....

Comment: No leakage or anything.  Just some stains, but the stuff on the walls is old.  Never thought of putting concrete floor paint on the walls.

Comment: Using floor paint on the walls is usually okay, just not the other way around.  Most floor paints are not designed for the wear.

Answer (score 2):

As already said by @Ecnerwal, you can re-coat Dryloc. Wire brushing to remove loose Dryloc and efflorescence is important surface prep, so is removing all the dust and particles from the brushing prior to re-coating. Vacuuming and then wet ragging it once is usually sufficient but if you run your had over the wall after is has dried from wet ragging and still feel dust, wet rag it again. Wear a good dust mask at least when brushing it. Too stiff a brush doesn't work too well as it tends just to scrape into even well bonded paint films.  Too soft a brush doesn't work too well either if it isn't stiff enough to remove loose material completely.  If the wall is dry as you have said, this is probably the best choice in terms of bang for the buck/time.

A note about floor epoxies.  They are designed to self-level and the more solids they have the more the epoxy will want to follow the force of gravity down the wall. The film thickness at the top of the wall will be less than the thickness lower in the wall, if there are void and surface roughness these will fill as you coat and then drain out on the wall slowly and epoxy, after it working time, can't usually be smoothed out. Before you purchase a floor epoxy to put on the wall verify with the epoxy manufacture that it will work for your application.  Also, for epoxy to adhere well over the long term it is not uncommon (when professionally done) to shot-blast (best), grind or acid etch the surface the epoxy will be applied to.  Shot-blasting the walls would probably work if the concrete is in good shape.  But this is expensive and messy and not a typical diy undertaking.  If you choose an epoxy, make sure to read and follow the manufacture's surface preparation instructions. Epoxy done poorly is difficult, very messy and expensive to remove.